# Android, Error inflating class ImageButton

Tags: android, xml

Опираясь на доки Google, сменил `minSdkVersion` своего проекта с 23 на 19, из - за чего часть виджетов в вёрстке отвалилась.

`android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton` не поддерживается на Api 19, поэтому для этого элемента я создал отдельный layout, заменив элемент на простой `ImageButton`. Однако на устройстве с Api19 приложение падает с ошибкой `Error inflating class ImageButton`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
 <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/event_favourite"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_min"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_mid"
                android:src="@drawable/favourite_selector"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Экспериментально я установил, что падает из - за:

`android:src="@drawable/favourite_selector"`

Без него всё работает(layout подгружается нужный и ничего не падает), но кнопка имеет дефолтный вид.

В самом селекторе нет ничего безобидного, поэтому я не понимаю причину падения:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_star" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_star" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_star_border" />
</selector>
```

`ic_star` и `ic_star_border` это vector - ассеты из стандартной либы Android Studio, имеют нормальный размер и разрешение. Помогите разобраться в причине падения или намекните, куда копнуть.

**UPD:** замена `android:src` на `app:srcCompat` ничего не меняет.

**UPD1:** `@drawable/favourite_selector` существует в единственном экземпляре и находится в общей папке, не в `drawavle - v21` или чём - то подобном. Изображения - аналогично.

Полный лог ошибки не информативен вообще, однако куда же без него:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: calendar.assi.ru.digitalcalendar, PID: 2758
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #164: Error inflating class ImageButton
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
        at android.databinding.DataBindingUtil.inflate(DataBindingUtil.java:126)
        at calendar.assi.ru.digitalcalendar.databinding.EventItemBinding.inflate(EventItemBinding.java:92)
        at calendar.assi.ru.digitalcalendar.databinding.EventItemBinding.inflate(EventItemBinding.java:86)
        at calendar.assi.ru.digitalcalendar.adapters.EventAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(EventAdapter.java:48)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6794)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5975)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5858)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5854)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2230)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1557)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1517)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:612)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3924)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3641)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4194)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
        at android.widget.TableLayout.onLayout(TableLayout.java:448)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
        at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:1231)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
        at android.view.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Заменил векторные изображения на png и всё заработало.
Теперь у меня исключительно для Api 19 не используются векторные иконки.
Без комментариев.